# Where can I get a list of categories?

Tags: mean-stack

This is not so much a specific programming related question but more on the planning part.

So I have posts in my DB that look like the below:

```
{
"_id": "57f88bb94b5342b2025d5646",
"postID": "12345",
"profileID": "12345678",
"title": "testT",
"description": "testD",
"views": 0,
"dateCreated": "2016-10-08 06:01:29",
"categories": [],
"__v": 0
```

}

Now, I am creating the front-end part for it and I need to create the categories from a dropdown list or something similar.

I know I can just populate it or get it from from the DB but where does the list actually come from? I mean say I need to create a post about Lamborghini, it comes under **brand** and **automobile** categories.

What I am essentially after is a place where I can grab these categories and their sub-categories.

Does anyone know of such a service/API? Is there another way?

By the way, I am on the MEAN Stack.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just created the list from all sorts of different sites and made it into one list.

Sadly, it looks like there is no such API service for this.